# How to Stream Strings to another Class

Tags: java, string, stream

I am working with the apache commons exec library. There i have a Stream that gives me a String from the console output.I want to get this Strings and send them to another class to finally send them to a client. i dont have any idea how to do that

Here is the stream and the line is the output from an executed jar

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setWorkingDirectory(dir);
    executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(new LogOutputStream() {
        @Override
        protected void processLine(String line, int level) {

            System.out.println("[LOL]"+line);
        }
    }));
```

And this is the other class where i want to send these Strings to a client:

```
String response = "";
try {


    he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
    while(ServerHandler.runningString.contains(parameter))
    {

        os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
    }

    os.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This Question is unclear. I do not see a connection between your code  samples. If you have a stream object whose contents you want to share with another method, just pass the stream object to the other method.

Comment: check this https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java